# How do I obtain the amulet in Candy Box

Tags: pc, candy-box

I currently have all the pieces of clothing except the old amulet. I would prefer to get it before I take on the castle keep quest but I have attempted all the currently available quests. Is it possible to get the amulet without doing the castle keep quest and if so, how do I get it?

Answer (score 1):

A quick google search for "The amulet candy box" brought up this [wiki page](http://candybox.wikia.com/wiki/An_old_amulet). On the page it states:

> An old amulet is an unlockable item in Candy Box. Obtained by killing the Walled In Zombie in the Castle's keep, it triples current candy production.

I suggest you do a quick google search before submitting questions.